# Laravel Validation skip through loops in Controller

Tags: forms, validation, if-statement, laravel-8

I have a form with four cards in it. I have a controller and a function to save the values in the form. In the controller, I have loops to see which cards are selected and get the input based on the cards selected. Without validation, the form could go through all the loops and save the input of the forms in the database, but when I added validation into the function, if I choose more than one card, error validation will only occur for the first loop and then it skips through all the other loop without validating. Is there any way for me to solve this validation error?

Controller:

```
public function save_detail(Request $request)
    {
        // get user info in session
        $user = $request->user();

        $application = Application::create([
            'app_type_id' => 1,
            'approval_status_id' => 1
        ]);

        $application->users()->save($user);

        if ($request->has('emp_name')) {
            $request->validate([
                 'emp_name'                  => 'required',
                 'emp_length'                => 'required',
                 'emp_monthly_gross_salary'  => 'required',
                 'monthly_allowance'         => 'required',
             ],[
                 'emp_name.required'                  => 'required',
                 'emp_length.required'                => 'required',
                 'emp_monthly_gross_salary.required'  => 'required',
                 'monthly_allowance.required'         => 'required',
             ]);

            $user->employment_detail()->updateOrCreate(
                ['user_id' => $request->user()],
                [
                    'emp_name' => $request->emp_name,
                    'emp_length' => $request->emp_length,
                    'emp_monthly_gross_salary' => sanitize_money($request->emp_monthly_gross_salary),
                    'monthly_allowance' => sanitize_money($request->monthly_allowance),
                ]
            );
        }

        if ($request->has('role')) {
            
             $request->validate([
                 'role'            => 'required',
                 'est_earnings'    => 'required',
             ],[
                 'role.required'                  => 'required',
                 'est_earnings.required'                => 'required',
             ]);

            $user->part_time()->firstOrCreate(
                [
                    'part_time_role' => $request->role,
                    'part_time_earning' => sanitize_money($request->est_earnings)
                ]
            );

        }

        if ($request->has('inv_name')) {

            $request->validate([
                 'inv_name'            => 'required',
                 'yearly_earning'    => 'required',
             ],[
                 'inv_name.required'                  => 'required',
                 'yearly_earning.required'                => 'required',
             ]);

            $user->borrower_investment_income()->firstOrCreate(
                [
                'invest_source_specify' => $request->inv_name,
                'invest_year_earning' => sanitize_money($request->yearly_earning)
                ]
            );

        }

        $user->user_current_step = Constant::CURR_STEP_COMMITMENT;
        $user->save();

        alert('success','Your income are saved.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($value as $val)
{
  $request->validate([
                 'emp_name'                  => 'required',
                 'emp_length'                => 'required',
                 'emp_monthly_gross_salary'  => 'required',
                 'monthly_allowance'         => 'required',
             ],[
                 'emp_name.required'                  => 'required',
                 'emp_length.required'                => 'required',
                 'emp_monthly_gross_salary.required'  => 'required',
                 'monthly_allowance.required'         => 'required',
             ]);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hii can i ask what the value refers to in your code?